# How to set PHP variables via JavaScript to hide images at certain viewport widths

Tags: javascript, php, css, media-queries

Hello I just switched to responsive layout on my website dedicated to online gaming and I'm struggling to find a way to load a different number of thumbnails displayed for my "Featured games" section depending on screen size.

the code looks like this:

```
<div class='section-title'><h1 class="text_h1">Featured games</h1> 
</div>
<br class='clear' />
   <div class='flex-container'>
       <div class="feat">
<?php echo akd_list("feat","rand()","7"); ?>
       </div>
   </div>
<br class='clear' />
```

As one can see the number of thumbnails to be displayed is manually set as a returned parameter inside de akd_list php function inside my CMS and in this case is set to 7.

My need is that this number to be set automatically depending on the screen size for example if screen resolution is smaller then 700px set this number to 4, if between 1024 and 1200 set it to 5 and so on.

I believe I need to use some javascript and have a variable store this number depending on the detected screen size then pass it to akd_list php output as a parameter, yet as my coding skills in javascript tends to zero I would really appreciate a bit of help.

Comment: Why not have a look at some tutorials about this? SO is not a free code-writing service, and even with some further requirements (under which rules should which number be outputted there), this is not too hard. Additionally, this has no connection to PHP or CSS

Comment: You could make use of ajax and send the screen width to the server that way, making use of the server response to generate the html.

Comment: James Jayson thank you very much for you answer, yet a bit of code would help alot

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to have PHP always output all seven (or whatever the maximum is) thumbnails, and hide some of them using media queries.

```html
<div class="feat">
  <img class="thumbnail" src="..." />
  <!-- another six images here -->
</div>
```

```css
/* at viewport widths of 700px and smaller, hide last 3 thumbnails */
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .thumbnail:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* at viewport widths of 1200px and smaller, hide last 2 thumbnails */
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .thumbnail:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/70dnh34u/

If you feel you have an issue with images potentially being loaded that won't end up being displayed, it may be an indication that responsive design isn't suitable for your project, and you may wish to look at having a separate page/site for small devices/mobile. But I'd suggest keeping it simple as above with a view to keeping things manageable where it's reasonable to do so. You can check in browser dev tools whether or not the images are loaded when viewing at certain widths.

Comment: I understand your approch did something similar with css to hide elements, yet by looking at the source code of the html page you can still see the thumbnails are actualy there just now showing to the user,

Comment: Yes, that's right. The last paragraph in my answers refers to this. Do you see it as a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use mobile_detect.php from http://mobiledetect.net/ like this
I use this mobile_detect class sometimes to display different content depending on the users device.

```
<?php
// Include and instantiate the class.
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

$number = 7;

// Any mobile device.
if ( $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() ) {
 $number = 3;
}

// Any tablet device.
if( $detect->isTablet() ){
 $number = 5;
}
?>

<div class='section-title'><h1 class="text_h1">Featured games</h1> 
</div>
<br class='clear' />
   <div class='flex-container'>
       <div class="feat">
<?php echo akd_list("feat","rand()",$number); ?>
       </div>
   </div>
<br class='clear' />
```